# how do I prevent re-render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, lazy-loading

Now I have created this custom hook to perform lazy loading,which takes redux slice action as input and

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function useLazyFetch(fetchAction) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const loadMoreRef = useRef(null);

  const handleObserver = useCallback(async(entries) => {
    const [target] = entries;
    console.log(target.isIntersecting);
    if (target.isIntersecting) {
        console.log("INTERSECTING.....");
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
        setPage((prev) => prev + 1);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const option = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 1.0,
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleObserver, option);

    if (loadMoreRef.current) observer.observe(loadMoreRef.current);
  }, [handleObserver]);

  const fetchApi = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
      dispatch(fetchAction(page))

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }, [page,fetchAction,dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApi();
  }, [fetchApi]);

  return { loading, loadMoreRef };
}

export default useLazyFetch;
```

I am using this in my component like this, here you can see I am tracking div in the bottom using loadMoreRef from useLazyFetch, Now when I am commenting out the **fetchApi();** from custom hook its working as expected, on scroll its logging INTERSECTING... in the console but the moment I try to execute the action through fetchApi() my whole app goes into loop,the div tracker with ref comes to top and it fetches the posts but after immediately that action repeats the tracker comes to top and page becomes empty & it fetches next set of posts,I can see that my list is getting appended new set of posts to state in redux dev tool instead of completely setting new state, but in UI it's rendering all posts again and again whic is causing the loop,how can I avoid this ?

```
import { CircularProgress, Grid, IconButton, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
import React, { useEffect,useRef,useState } from "react";
import AssistantIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Assistant";
import Post from "../components/Post";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "../redux/postSlice";
import AddPost from "../components/AddPost";

import useLazyFetch from "../hooks/useLazyFetch";


export default function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // const api =  `https://picsum.photos/v2/list`
  const { status, posts } = useSelector((state) => state.post);
  const {loading,loadMoreRef} = useLazyFetch(getPosts)



  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box borderBottom="1px solid #ccc" padding="8px 20px">
        <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Home</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <IconButton>
              <AssistantIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <Box  height="92vh" sx={{ overflowY: "scroll" }}>
        <AddPost />
        <Box textAlign="center" marginTop="1rem">
          {status === "loading" && (
            <CircularProgress size={20} color="primary" />
          )}
        </Box>
        {status === "success" &&
          posts?.map((post) => <Post key={post._id} post={post} />)}
         <div style={{height:"50px",width:"100px",backgroundColor:"red"}} ref={loadMoreRef}>{loading && <p>loading...</p>}</div>
         
        

      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

And here is my redux action & state update part

```
const initialState = {
  status: "idle",
  posts: []
};

export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk("post/getPosts", async (page) => {
  console.log(page);
  console.log("calling api ...");
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/posts?page=${page}`);
  return data;
});


export const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "post",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getPosts.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    [getPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.posts = [...state.posts,...action.payload.response.posts] ;
    },
    [getPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed";
    },
}
```

Comment: It would be really useful since your code is a little complexe to create a working example by forking this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and share the link. And you can use a fake api with pagination like [Jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com).

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution that is working

```
import { CircularProgress, Grid, IconButton, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
import React, { useEffect,useMemo } from "react";
import AssistantIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Assistant";
import Post from "../components/Post";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "../redux/postSlice";
import AddPost from "../components/AddPost";
import useLazyFetch from "../hooks/useLazyFetch";

export default function Home() {
  const { status, posts } = useSelector((state) => state.post);
  const {loading,loadMoreRef} = useLazyFetch(getPosts)


const renderedPostList = useMemo(() => (
  posts.map((post) => {
    return( <Post key={post._id.toString()} post={post} />)
  })
), [posts]) 

  
  return (
    <Box>
      <Box borderBottom="1px solid #ccc" padding="8px 20px">
        <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Home</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <IconButton>
              <AssistantIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <Box height="92vh" sx={{ overflowY: "scroll" }}>
        <AddPost />
        <Box textAlign="center" marginTop="1rem">
          {status === "loading" && (
            <CircularProgress size={20} color="primary" />
          )}
        </Box>
        {renderedPostList}
        <div style={{height:"50px",width:"100px",backgroundColor:"red"}} ref={loadMoreRef}>{loading && <p>loading...</p>}</div>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
}
```

I used useMemo hook to memoize and it works as expected